# Bluetooth low energy (BLE 112 ) Difference between BGAPI and BGScript

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

What is the Difference between BGAPI and BGScript ?

And if we write any code for BG profile than how can we burn it in BLE 112?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BGAPI interface defines the protocol used to talk to the module over USB or serial link.

BGScript is something which runs on the module processor itself, when the USB or serial link is not used.

I have the dongle, BLED112, which is the same thing as BLE112 with a USB connector on it, and the code is "burned" to it using standard USB DFU interface.

The downloading of the code to BLE112 can be done using several methods:

(1) Bring out the DD, DC debug interface pins from your module and use the CC-Debugger (digikey part 296-30207-ND, $55). This works every time. If you have the DKBLE112 kit, the CC-Debugger fits on the 10-pin .050 connector in lower right corner. You can "burn" any firmware and any stack this way. Works awesome.

(2) Hope that the current firmware on the CC2540 has serial bootloader, and load the new firmware (hopefully also containing serial bootloader) using UART. TI has the tools, but it sure seems quite convoluted to me, and I did not try it.

Comment: Thanks for the brief answer. How can i burn my code for BLE112. am using serial link?

Comment: @UsmanAli - Usually, you'll have some sort of exposed debugger interface that will let you upload the firmware you compiled from your BGScript. For example, the BLE112 evaluation board comes with pins that you can plug TI's CC Debugger into and upload new firmware via that route.

Comment: Just for people who are Googling and finding this later on, I wrote a post based on a Bluegiga app-note on the differences between BGScript, BGApi, and BGLib here: http://www.sureshjoshi.com/embedded/bgscript-bglib-bgapi-explained/

BGAPI is a custom binary protocol used to externally control the modules and dongles. BGAPI is a protocol specification only.

BGLib is an ANSI C reference implementation of the BGAPI binary protocol.

BGScript is a scripting language which takes care of the Bluetooth Smart stack internally, exposing only what is necessary in the form of easy commands and events.