# How would I go about programming a bluetooth emitter to work with iOS or Android?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, arduino, hardware, firmware

If I purchase a bluetooth emitter that I'd like to use as a beacon, I need to burn a UUID onto a bluetooth device. I've googled a bit, but the results are polluted with tutorials for pairing headsets and speakers with phones and cars. I'm not necessarily looking to use Arduino, which I understand can use USB, because those kits tend to be more expensive than mass-produced BLE units.

How would I go about burning code or data onto a bluetooth emitter? Is there a standardized process, or does it vary by manufacturer? It seems like I'm essentially programming the device, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for Stack Overflow. If it isn't please guide me to the right website. Don't just vote to close. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Arduinos are great to build prototypes with, and bluetooth shields are available. If you are looking to mass produce something for an app, COGS become super important and you will want to go with something else. It does vary by manufacturer and there are many possible directions. I would go with Bluegiga's [BLE 112](http://www.bluegiga.com/evaluation_BLE112). You have to start an account there and log in, but they do have a sample app, which is a great way to get started with the Core Bluetooth Framework.

You can buy the development kit (which will cost you more than an Arduino and Bluetooth Shield), or if you aren't averse to breadboards, you can just buy a CC Debugger and a standalone Bluegiga BLE112 module. This website gives a good introduction on how they are programmed on a breadboard: http://blog.bluetooth-smart.com/2012/09/16/programming-the-ble112-using-bgscript/

There is also a good question on StackOverflow regarding the BlueGiga kit: [BlueGiga BLE development tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992201/bluegiga-ble-development-tools).

Again this is just one of many different directions you can go.